# Google Sheets script editor execution fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, elementor

I did a Google sheets webhook integration with the wordpress elementor form per this tutorial: https://geshet.io/connect-elementor-form-and-google-sheets-for-free-without-zapier/

Form submissions get automatically added in the sheet - all good.

But it only worked on the spreadsheet that I created. In client’s account, first of all I could not deploy the script because I didn’t belong to *their* organization. Then, I walked one of their employees through the steps and set up / deployed the script from their company gmail account. But for some reason now script execution fails even though the setup was identical.

Could this be tied to Google user permissions and such? Not sure where to look.

Comment: Does it show any errors? Have you tried executing it on incognito mode? What steps are you using to deploy it on clients?

Comment: no specific errors - it only shows that script execution failed. Not sure what would be the point of an incognito mode. Deployment steps are illustrated in the link that I included. It's a "web app" script deployment in the script editor.